# What's this loading effect named?

Tags: javascript

[image: tec]

I wonder what is this loading effect named? Thanks. I want to use this technique but don't know what's the keyword to google.

Comment: https://uxdesign.cc/what-you-should-know-about-skeleton-screens-a820c45a571a?gi=9d56f16975a0 read this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skeleton screens with progressive loading

https://css-tricks.com/building-skeleton-screens-css-custom-properties/

https://ant.design/components/skeleton/